# How can i solve ManyToOne(AddressType) inside OneToMany(UserAddress) inside OneToMany(User) on form collections symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, formcollection

I'm working with symfony2 form collections, and in any point of app i had this error:

`cannot convert AddressType to string`

My User entity

```
/**
 * @var $addresses
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserAddress", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $addresses;
```

(...)

```
/**
 * Set addresses
 *
 * @param Collection $addresses
 * @return User
 */
public function setAddresses(Collection $addresses) : User
{
    if(! $addresses instanceof Collection){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("$addresses must be an instance of Collection");
    }

    $this->addresses = $addresses;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add address
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\UserAddress $address
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\UserAddress $address)
{
    if(! $address instanceof UserAddress) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("$address must be an instance of UserAddress");
    }

    if(!$this->addresses->contains($address)) {
        $address->setUser($this);
        $this->emails->add($address);
    }

    $this->addresses[] = $address;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove address
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\UserAddress $address
 */
public function removeAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\UserAddress $address)
{
    if(! $address instanceof UserAddress) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("$address must be an instance of UserAddress");
    }

    $this->addresses->removeElement($address);
}

/**
 * Get addresses
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getAddresses()
{
    return $this->addresses;
}
```

My UserAddress Entity

```
/**
 * @var
 * Many addresses have one address type.
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\AddressType", inversedBy="userAddressType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $addressType;
```

(...)

```
/**
 * Add addressType
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\AddressType $addressType
 *
 * @return UserAddress
 */
public function addAddressType(\AppBundle\Entity\AddressType $addressType)
{
    if(! $addressType instanceof UserType && $addressType !== null){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("$addressType must be an instance of AddressType, or null");
    }

    $this->addressType[] = $addressType;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove addressType
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\AddressType $addressType
 */
public function removeAddressType(\AppBundle\Entity\AddressType $addressType)
{
    if(! $addressType instanceof UserType && $addressType !== null){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("$addressType must be an instance of AddressType, or null");
    }

    $this->addressType->removeElement($addressType);
}

/**
 * Set addressType
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\AddressType $addressType
 *
 * @return UserAddress
 */
public function setAddressType(\AppBundle\Entity\AddressType $addressType = null)
{
    if(! $addressType instanceof User && $addressType !== null) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("$addressType must be an instance of AddressType, or null");
    }

    $this->addressType = $addressType;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get addressType
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\AddressType
 */
public function getAddressType()
{
    return $this->addressType;
}
```

My AddressType Entity

```
/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserAddress", mappedBy="addressType")
 */
private $userAddressType;
```

(...)

```
/**
 * Add userAddressType
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\UserAddress $userAddressType
 *
 * @return AddressType
 */
public function addUserAddressType(\AppBundle\Entity\UserAddress $userAddressType)
{
    $this->userAddressType[] = $userAddressType;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove userAddressType
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\UserAddress $userAddressType
 */
public function removeUserAddressType(\AppBundle\Entity\UserAddress $userAddressType)
{
    $this->userAddressType->removeElement($userAddressType);
}

/**
 * Get userAddressType
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getUserAddressType()
{
    return $this->userAddressType;
}
```

And this is in Form UserType:

```
->add('addresses', CollectionType::class,
            [
                'entry_type' => UserAddressType::class,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ]
        );
```

The problem is, when i run in editAction for example, this error happens

`Cannot convert AddressType to string`

Thanks for help!

---

EDIT:

I've found the answer reading

http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#pre-populating-the-form-formevents-pre-set-data-and-formevents-post-set-data

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this as the result of not having a proper `__toString()` method on my Entity classes, so the `select` is then unable to render the proper "value" and exceptions on spitting the full object in place of a representative string.